# 360° HDRI map issue in Eevee

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, hardware

I installed the new version and the world (default HDRI maps of world) doesn't appear correctly in viewport shading. I can see it in viewport just like in ortho mode or some kind of. How can i fix it?

[image]

[image]

I reinstalled Blender - same result.

The problem is with Evee, Cycles works fine in this situation.

I've tried installing version 2.80 - same thing. Looks like my harware doesn't support Evee... I've got Intel core i5 660.

If i mark "scene light" and "scene world" Evee seems to work well 
though...:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, according to these requirements:

https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

and the fact that my PC is older than 10 years, looks like Evee render engine doesn't support my processor (i5 660), or support it some strange way (without world's HDRI maps).